# tcpdf not supporting https?

Tags: https, tcpdf

when we add to our htaccess file the following lines:

```
 RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

we receive the following errors:

```
Warning: getimagesize(/icon/logo_print.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home2/example/public_html/tcpdf/include/tcpdf_images.php on line 171

Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(/icon/logo_print.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home2/example/public_html/tcpdf/tcpdf.php on line 7039
TCPDF ERROR: [Image] Unable to get the size of the image: /image/1/SB_m.gif
```

relevant code:

```
class MYPDF extends FPDI { //  extends TCPDF 

  public function Header() { // Page header

  global $dbcmpName;

$html = <<<EOF
<table cellpadding="2" >
    <tr>
        <td><img src="/icon/logo_print.jpg" alt="$dbcmpName Logo" style="border:none;" /></td>
        <td><span class="header1" >$dbcmpName</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
EOF;

    // output the HTML content:
    $this->SetFont('verdana', '', 9);
    $this->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
  }

 ...


      if ( file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/image/' . $prodFamilly . '/'. $db->f('prd_photo')) )  { 
$html .= '
        <img src="/image/' . $prodFamilly . '/' . $db->f('prd_photo') . '" alt="' . $imgAlt . '" />     
';
      } 


// output the HTML content:
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');

...
```

Note: there is a similiar question - [TCPDF cache problems when using https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040804/tcpdf-cache-problems-when-using-https)
but in this question, they use different way to show the image, without HTML,
and when trying to adapt the proposed answer, I couldnot find the code suggested to change in tcpdf file, probably because we use different version of tcpdf:

```
// File name   : tcpdf.php
// Version     : 6.2.13
// Begin       : 2002-08-03
// Last Update : 2015-06-18
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using tcpdf version 6.2.26 instead of 6.2.13 seems to solve my problem.

They change img URL in version 6.2.25, maybe this is the fix I needed